# NER types for 'en' model?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy

Is there a way to get all the built-in and added custom NER types in spaCy? The method suggested [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/441) doesn't seem to work anymore. On trying

```
nlp.entity.cfg
```

I get back,

```
{u'hist_size': 0, u'pretrained_dims': 0L, u'hist_width': 0, u'beam_density': 
0.0, u'cnn_maxout_pieces': 3, u'maxout_pieces': 2, u'hidden_depth': 1, 
u'token_vector_width': 128, u'nr_class': 73, u'beam_width': 1, 
u'hidden_width': 200}
```

There are no 'actions' and 'extra_labels' keys in this dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found another way. Works for spacy v. 3.0.5:

```
ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
print(ner.labels)
```

it gives the result:

```
('CARDINAL', 'DATE', 'EVENT', 'FAC', 'GPE', 'LANGUAGE', 'LAW', 'LOC', 'MONEY', 'NORP', 'ORDINAL', 'ORG', 'PERCENT', 'PERSON', 'PRODUCT', 'QUANTITY', 'TIME', 'WORK_OF_ART')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for newer versions of spaCy, as `nlp.entity` has become obsolete for quite some time now.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if this is the way it's to be done. I figured out on calling

```
nlp.entity.move_names
```

returns,

```
[u'B-PERSON', u'B-CARDINAL', u'B-ORG', u'B-GPE', u'B-FAC', u'B-MONEY', u'B-NORP', u'B-DATE', u'B-TIME', u'B-ORDINAL', u'B-PERCENT', u'B-PRODUCT', u'B-LANGUAGE', u'B-LOC', u'B-QUANTITY', u'B-WORK_OF_ART', u'B-EVENT', u'B-LAW', u'I-PERSON', u'I-CARDINAL', u'I-ORG', u'I-GPE', u'I-FAC', u'I-MONEY', u'I-NORP', u'I-DATE', u'I-TIME', u'I-ORDINAL', u'I-PERCENT', u'I-PRODUCT', u'I-LANGUAGE', u'I-LOC', u'I-QUANTITY', u'I-WORK_OF_ART', u'I-EVENT', u'I-LAW', u'L-PERSON', u'L-CARDINAL', u'L-ORG', u'L-GPE', u'L-FAC', u'L-MONEY', u'L-NORP', u'L-DATE', u'L-TIME', u'L-ORDINAL', u'L-PERCENT', u'L-PRODUCT', u'L-LANGUAGE', u'L-LOC', u'L-QUANTITY', u'L-WORK_OF_ART', u'L-EVENT', u'L-LAW', u'U-PERSON', u'U-CARDINAL', u'U-ORG', u'U-GPE', u'U-FAC', u'U-MONEY', u'U-NORP', u'U-DATE', u'U-TIME', u'U-ORDINAL', u'U-PERCENT', u'U-PRODUCT', u'U-LANGUAGE', u'U-LOC', u'U-QUANTITY', u'U-WORK_OF_ART', u'U-EVENT', u'U-LAW', u'O']
```

This also shows any additional custom entities added to the model, like u'EMAIL' in my case:

```
[u'B-PERSON', u'B-CARDINAL', u'B-ORG', u'B-GPE', u'B-FAC', u'B-MONEY', u'B-NORP', u'B-DATE', u'B-TIME', u'B-ORDINAL', u'B-PERCENT', u'B-PRODUCT', u'B-LANGUAGE', u'B-LOC', u'B-QUANTITY', u'B-WORK_OF_ART', u'B-EVENT', u'B-LAW', u'I-PERSON', u'I-CARDINAL', u'I-ORG', u'I-GPE', u'I-FAC', u'I-MONEY', u'I-NORP', u'I-DATE', u'I-TIME', u'I-ORDINAL', u'I-PERCENT', u'I-PRODUCT', u'I-LANGUAGE', u'I-LOC', u'I-QUANTITY', u'I-WORK_OF_ART', u'I-EVENT', u'I-LAW', u'L-PERSON', u'L-CARDINAL', u'L-ORG', u'L-GPE', u'L-FAC', u'L-MONEY', u'L-NORP', u'L-DATE', u'L-TIME', u'L-ORDINAL', u'L-PERCENT', u'L-PRODUCT', u'L-LANGUAGE', u'L-LOC', u'L-QUANTITY', u'L-WORK_OF_ART', u'L-EVENT', u'L-LAW', u'U-PERSON', u'U-CARDINAL', u'U-ORG', u'U-GPE', u'U-FAC', u'U-MONEY', u'U-NORP', u'U-DATE', u'U-TIME', u'U-ORDINAL', u'U-PERCENT', u'U-PRODUCT', u'U-LANGUAGE', u'U-LOC', u'U-QUANTITY', u'U-WORK_OF_ART', u'U-EVENT', u'U-LAW', u'O', u'B-EMAIL', u'I-EMAIL', u'L-EMAIL', u'U-EMAIL']
```